# Why does the keys of PDO query() result contain tablename?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I connected mysql with PDO like this:

```php
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'atlas';
        $table = 'homepage_pv';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = 'mysql';
        $conn = null;
        try {
            $conn = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
                $username,
                $password,
                array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                )
            );
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "connect to mysql failed : " . $e->getMessage();
            $conn = null;
            exit;
        }

        $result = $conn->query('SELECT * from homepage_pv')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
        echo "result=" . json_encode($result);
```

the result is :

```
result=[{"homepage_pv.id":"1","homepage_pv.datetime":"2019-08-19 22:56:26"},{"homepage_pv.id":"2","homepage_pv.datetime":"2019-08-19 22:56:28"},{"homepage_pv.id":"3","homepage_pv.datetime":"2019-08-19 23:01:58"}]
```

The keys contain the table name "homepage_pv" , which is not expected;
But where I create PDO like this :

```php
        try {
            $conn = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=$servername;",
               ...
            );
        }
        ...
        $result = $conn->query('SELECT * from atlas.homepage_pv')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
        echo "result=" . json_encode($result);
```

the keys in the result do not contain tablename any more, like this:

```php
result=[{"id":"1","datetime":"2019-08-19 22:56:26"},{"id":"2","datetime":"2019-08-19 22:56:28"},{"id":"3","datetime":"2019-08-19 23:01:58"},{"id":"4","datetime":"2019-08-19 23:08:48"}]
```

In case1 , I specified dbname when creating PDO and leaved out it when doing query;
In case2 , it's is on the contrary;

So what cause it? how can I specify dbname when creating PDO without the keys in result containing tablename?

Answer (score 1):

Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in `fetchAll()`. If you use `PDO::FETCH_NAMED` it will return with alias name. If alias not present then with the table name. Attaching the [doc](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_NAMED) for your further reference.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the doc or documentation, but it is better than the official docs. 